# How to adjust height of <hr> in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, height

I'm making the header of my website and decided to use hr between navigation links instead of border property since I didn't wanna get into nth child pseudo. Navigation links and logo wrapper are aligned in the center and I stretched hr element.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: "martian", serif;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

hr {
  align-self: stretch;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <a href="" class="nav-link">Classroom</a>
    <hr>
    <a href="" class="nav-link">Manual</a>
    <hr>
    <div class="logo-wrapper">
      <a href="homepage.html" class="logo"><img src="images/tgm_logo.png" class="logo"></a>
      <p class="motto">Engineering Behind Great Inventions</p>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <a href="" class="nav-link">About</a>
    <hr>
    <a href="" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
  </nav>
</header>
```

I want to shorten the hr instead of strecthing it through the whole container, maybe third of the height. I would appreciate your help.
[How it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLTF9.png)

I tried giving a height attribute to the hr instead of streching it, however it just got vanished after doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explicitly specifying `height` for `hr` works fine. You probably tried to use percentages.

Regarding percentages, [MDN notes for `height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height#formal_definition):

> If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly
> ... the (percentage) value computes to `auto`.

Since `nav` hasn't specified a `height` value explicitly, `hr` falls back to `auto`, which [(for Flexbox Layout) means `min-content`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox/#min-size-auto) in this case I believe. This would be the reason why your `hr` seems to "vanish".

If you **specify an explicit height to `nav`**, you can use percentages on `hr` as you'd expect. Alternatively, you could also **specify an explicit height to `hr`** directly.

Or (but still with explicit values), you could **use margins**: Having a margin will reduce the element's size it can stretch to.

---

**Note**: [HTML5 defines the `<hr>` element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-hr-element) as "a paragraph-level thematic break". Similarly, [ARIA defines the `separator` role](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/separator_role) (i.e. `<hr>`'s implicit role) as "a divider that separates and distinguishes sections of content or groups of menuitems".

Unless you deem it reasonable to divide all your navigation items into separate groups (with only one item each!), you should think about declaring some of your `<hr>` elements with the [`presentation` role](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/presentation_role).

Or, you could use pseudo-elements to create visual separators, e.g. like this:

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
}
li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

/*Separator before every subsequent LI*/
li+li::before {
  content: "";
  width: 1px;
  height: 80%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: black;
}

a {
  padding: .8rem .4rem;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href>Home</a></li>
    <li><a href>About</a></li>
    <li><a href>Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `height` is working good for me.

You just have to resize it absolutely, as using `px`, `pt`, `mm`, etc.

Using `%` makes it height 0 because of 0-height parent element.